# Ionic alert label not display

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm used Ionic 3 and I'm try to display label for behind the input fields ,but it's not display,why is not showing? please help me to fix it

Thanks

```
 doPrompt() {
        let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: '5 Rooms Available',
          message: "",

        inputs: [

            {
              label: "Single Rooms (3)",
              name: 'Single Rooms (3)',
              placeholder: '$200.00',


            },

          ],

          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              handler: data => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Set',
              handler: data => {
                console.log('Saved clicked');
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        prompt.present();
      }
```

Comment: You can only use lable for (only for radio/checkbox inputs)

Comment: oh !!! @PareshGami sir thanks for the advice, :)

Comment: @PareshGami Hello, I have an issue that when the text in label is long, it gets truncated(dots come at the last). How to fix that.

Comment: @ShubhamAnand Can you please show me screenshot so I can get a more clear idea

Comment: Fixed it yesterday. Thanks for your concern BTW.

Comment: @ShubhamAnand Please put the solution

Comment: My issue was a little different from the question asked. In my alert, label was coming, but the it was getting truncated at the last. @core114 if you are facing the same issue, I can post the solution.

Comment: @ShubhamAnand Thanks for the informed, Actually Its not my issue